# Diferencia entre "del que" y "de que"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sintaxis

No tengo claro si hay alguna diferencia en "de que" y "del que".
Por ejemplo, "El dinero del que dispone el banco" y "El dinero de que dispone el banco". Me suena más habitual la primera opción, aunque más correcta o formal la segunda, pero ambas con el mismo significado.
¿Que papel juega el "el" de "del que"?

Según Ngram,la segunda opción es más habitual, pero está en declive frente a la primera, que va en aumento. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas formas (conocidas como "grupos preposicionales relativos") son correctas. La pregunta puede hacerse extensiva a otras preposiciones (*a, con, en, por*) y se limita a los casos **en (los) que** (véase que acabo de usar las dos formas posibles en cuestión) el referente no es personal, puesto que si esto ocurre todas las formas son igualmente comunes:

- La mujer **de quien** te hablo es famosa.
- La mujer **de la que/cual** te hablo es famosa.

Existe -- me parece -- una cierta resistencia a usar la estructura "preposición + *que*" porque la relativa define al sustantivo indefinido, y "que" pareciera despojarlo de esa definición. Veamos con ejemplos:

- Te expones a un peligro grave. ("un" es un artículo indefinido.)
- El peligro **al que / a que** te expones es grave. (Al utilizarse una relativa especificativa -- sin comas -- el sustantivo "peligro" pasa a ser un sustantivo definido -- como lo demuestra la aparición del artículo "el" en lugar de "un" -- y eso hace que la mayoría de los hablantes se sientan inclinados a utilizar la forma relativa definida "el que".)

En el caso de tu ejemplo, la relativa proviene de una oración donde el sustantivo incontable viene sin artículo, en línea con su indefinición:

- El banco dispone **de dinero**.

Al decir:

- El dinero **del que** dispone el banco...

estamos limitando la cantidad de dinero a los fondos que el banco posee, y esto es razonable en la práctica y correcto desde el punto de vista gramatical.

La forma:

- El dinero **de que** dispone el banco...

parece querer conservar la indefinición de la oración original (*El banco dispone de dinero*).

Otro ejemplo:

- Esta prenda está hecha **con algodón** importado.

Al decir:

- El algodón **con el que** está hecha esta prenda es importado

el sustantivo "algodón" pierde su indefinición (ya estamos hablando de un tipo de algodón en particular: el que se usó para fabricar esta prenda).

En cambio, esta oración:

- El algodón **con que** está hecha esta prenda es importado

pretende conservar la indefinición original del sustantivo "algodón".

**Nota**: He encontrado un interesante [apunte](https://psicologiaeducativa.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/tema-5.pdf) en Internet que, si bien no tiene autor, parece muy acertado por la precisión de sus conceptos y el modo en que está redactado:

El apunte (que prácticamente transcribo a continuación) dice que en los relativos complejos preposicionales puede omitirse el artículo en función de cuatro aspectos:

1. La preposición.
2. El tipo de oración de relativo.
3. El antecedente del relativo.
4. La estructura sintáctica de la oración.

(1) El primer factor es pertinente porque en el español actual solo las preposiciones monosílabas *a, con, de* y *en* pueden combinarse con el *que* relativo desprovisto del artículo determinado, como en estos ejemplos:
“Alguna quiere que nos dé la cifra **a que** están reducidos los fieles”; “el rosario de violencias **con que** la había castigado en los últimos meses”; “—Sí —respondió con toda la sangre fría **de que** era capaz “; “Completamente
dedicado a sí mismo, no advirtió el sobresalto de Laura ni la ansiedad **en que** iba envuelta su siguiente pregunta”.

Solo esporádicamente se documenta la omisión del artículo con la preposición *por*, como en "La verdadera razón **por que** quieres quedarte es Miguel, ¿no es verdad?" (Allende, Casa).

(2) La omisión del artículo es más frecuente en las relativas especificativas, como “La pluma estilográfica dorada **con que** solía firmar los documentos importantes”, que en las explicativas. Se registra, no obstante, la omisión en estas últimas, sobre todo en textos de los siglos XIX y XX, y a menudo en los complementos preposicionales de hablar, referirse y otros verbos que aluden
a algo que ya se ha mencionado: “Malinche nació en un pueblito vecino de Coazacualco, **en que** se hablaba el azteca y el idioma de los mayas”; ““El brillo del diablo”, **de que** me había hablado Angustias, aparecía empobrecido
y chillón”. La omisión del artículo en las explicativas es hoy algo más común en el español americano que en el europeo. De hecho, en el segundo se suele percibir como arcaísmo.

(3) El tercer factor es relevante porque el artículo del relativo complejo se omite más frecuentemente cuando el antecedente se construye con un artículo definido que cuando se forma con uno indefinido. Así, la omisión del artículo resulta más natural en la forma en la que se comporta *que* en “Empezaron a
bailar abriendo luego una ronda **a la que** arrastraron a tu tía Adelfa vestida de novia remojada”. No obstante, suele omitirse el artículo con antecedentes cuantificativos (a menudo indefinidos) en las relativas preposicionales de infinitivo o de subjuntivo de interpretación prospectiva, como cuando se alude a un recurso o un instrumento: “Se levantó Camila como sonámbula, pidiendo a la fondera algo **con que** taparse para salir a la calle” (sonaría mal decir "algo con **lo** que taparse"); “El procesado ha sido revisado y no tiene consigo nada **con que** pueda atacar al señor Director” (no tendría sentido decir "nada con **lo** que pueda atacar").

Se han observado ciertas preferencias léxicas en la omisión del artículo. Así, es más frecuente con antecedentes que indican circunstancias de la acción, como día, hora, lugar, manera, modo, tiempo y otros similares: “Cómo Talanque cuenta a Esplandián y a Frandalo la manera **en que** los enemigos les entraran la montaña y del esfuerço que Esplandián les pone”; “El príncipe recuerda el día **en que**, durante una comida familiar en el Hofburg, recibió Elisabeth la noticia”; “Quiero tu piel, a la hora **en que** las tiendas acarician el celofán de los regalos”. La omisión del artículo conlleva potestativamente la de la preposición cuando la misma precede al relativo y a su antecedente. Alternan, en efecto, “en el lugar en (el) que solía dejarlo” y “en el lugar que solía dejarlo”. He aquí un ejemplo de esta última variante: “Se hicieron inmortales y tienen una gran plaza como monumento en el sitio que fueron fusilados”. Esta reducción preposicional, que también se da a veces cuando las preposiciones son distintas, está relacionada con la formación de locuciones conjuntivas: a
medida que, al tiempo que, en el grado que.

(4) Influye, por último, en la omisión del artículo la función sintáctica que desempeña el grupo relativo en la subordinada: la omisión se produce más frecuentemente en los complementos circunstanciales que en los de régimen. Así, el segmento subrayado es un complemento circunstancial en “De ahí que me
sorprendiera el desapego **con que** la ahora condesa hablaba de la emperatriz”, pero es complemento de régimen en “[…] como terapia necesaria para conseguir por fin la fama y el dinero **con el que** había soñado cuando no era más que un aprendiz de compositor musical”. No se omite el artículo incluido en el relativo complejo cuando el grupo preposicional relativo ejerce la función de complemento del nombre: “el libro {del que ~ * de que} solo pude leer el prólogo”; “la novela {de la que ~ * de que} solo conozco algunos fragmentos”.

Tampoco se omite el artículo en los relativos complejos introducidos por la preposición *a* en función de complemento indirecto: “El joven {al que ~ * a que} dieron el premio”, ni de complemento directo, como en “el candidato {al que ~ * a que} seleccionaron”. Si la relativa es especificativa, el objeto directo puede construirse sin *a*, y entonces es obligada la omisión del artículo. Alternan, pues, *a la que* y *que* en “Tiritaba toda al pensar en la gente desconocida a la que debería conocer”, pero es agramatical la variante “*… en la gente desconocida a que debería conocer”. Si la relativa es explicativa, la  preposición *a* se hace necesaria con antecedente definido de persona: “[…] con ella y con Yves Montand, al que conocí aquel mismo verano”. En otras condiciones puede usarse el relativo sin preposición: “Tres alumnos, que eligió entre los de mejor expediente”.

**Conclusión**: En el caso de "el dinero de(l) que dispone el banco", se confrontan dos factores arriba mencionados:

A. Por un lado, en la oración de origen "dinero" es indefinido, y esto haría a esa palabra candidata al uso del artículo en el relativo (*de**l** que*). Ver el factor (3) arriba mencionado.

Según (3), esta tendencia se da cuando estamos en presencia de una artículo indeterminado -- nada dice (3) acerca de la ausencia de artículo con sustantivos incontables en singular o con sustantivos contables en plural. En estos casos, a mi entender sólo la forma "preposición + *que*" es correcta:

- Necesito dinero **con que** pagar mis estudios.
- *Necesito dinero **con el que** pagar mis estudios.
- Necesito fondos **con que** pagar mis estudios.
- *Necesito fondos **con los que** pagar mis estudios.

B. Por otro lado, la preposición "de" introduce un complemento de régimen del verbo "disponer" (*disponer de*), que favorece la omisión del artículo (*de que*). Ver el factor (4) arriba mencionado.

En el caso que nos ocupa, "el dinero" lleva artículo determinado y si bien (3) dice que el uso del artículo con el relativo (*del que*) es más frecuente con artículos indeterminados, no dice que ese uso no corresponda cuando el artículo sea determinado. En cuanto a la función sintáctica, claramente estamos frente a un complemento de régimen, que favorece la omisión del artículo. Esto explica la coexistencia de ambas formas, "el dinero del que dispone el banco" y "el dinero de que dispone el banco", más allá de que la alternancia de ambas estructuras es casi una constante en los casos arriba descriptos como tales.

Comment: Solo mirando las oraciones, alguien se percató que "de que" es exclusivo con "de+que", mientras que "del que", "de los que", etc. Pareciera originario como un reemplazo forzado de "cual-cuales".  
> El dinero del que dispone el banco.  
> El dinero del cual dispone el banco.  
> Necesito fondos con los que pagar mis estudios.
> Necesito fondos con los cuales pagar mis estudios.
Si prueban hacer lo mismo con "de que" no funciona.